# Android - status bar prevents full screen

Tags: android, layout, fullscreen, statusbar

My app correctly runs in full screen when it's started. However after minimizing and then returning to the app, the status bar pops up and pushes my views down a little. How can I keep the status bar from moving my views?

Here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.draw"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
    <com.example.draw.DrawView 
        android:id="@+id/draw"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    />      
<com.admob.android.ads.AdView     
       android:id="@+id/ad" 
       android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       myapp:backgroundColor="#000000"
       myapp:primaryTextColor="#FFFFFF"
       myapp:secondaryTextColor="#CCCCCC"
       android:layout_gravity="bottom"
/>
```

Here is part of my activity's onCreate:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

I also have the fullscreen theme in the manifest:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Thanks

Comment: Which SDK version are you using? And are you running the app in the emulator or a real phone? Does is make a difference?

Comment: Hi, Did you find any sollution to your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are known bugs with the status bar / notification bar.

See:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3674

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8052

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5906

Answer (score 17):

You can fix this issue with:

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
```

(do that in onCreate).... note that **this will break the soft keyboard (IME) - as edittext can no longer slide into view above the keyboard.** That flag prevents the window from moving at all....

If you need an edit text to also work while fixing the status bug you can do

```
someEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
            } else {
                hideKeyboard();
                getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
            }   
        }
    });
```

Comment: I was encountering the same issue on two different activities and this solution was perfect for me. Thank you!

Comment: Do you have idea how it can be done in XML, not in the runtime? See my posted question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11215180/how-to-make-activity-theme-with-windowmanager-layoutparams-flag-layout-no-limits

Comment: You answer didn't help me at first, but then I set all focusable views to be non-focusable and non-focusableInTouchMode in my layout, and reset them back to focusable in onResume. That helped. Also, FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS didn't break soft keyboard for me. It'll probably break only for a certain windowSoftInputMode or for an editText with noExtractEditText set to false.

Answer (score 0):

Just android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" attribute on your activity on the manifest is enough. Hope its works

Comment: Nope. I have this in the manifest but just using this does not help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I changed the activity for the interstitial and deleted:
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"